# python permission access denied

Tags: python, windows

Issue with running Python scripts on company laptop

My device:

- Python3.8
- Windows10 (21H2)

I have been facing an issue with running Python scripts on my company laptop recently.

Previously, I was able to use Python without any problems, but today I encountered an error where I am unable to execute `.py` scripts.

To troubleshoot the issue, I have checked the python.exe file and verified that the environment variables path are set correctly.

[image]

However, when I tried running the command "`python -v`" in the terminal, I received an error message stating "permission denied."

[image]

I have consulted with my colleagues in the company, and they confirmed that they can still use Python as usual without any issues.

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this problem. Please let me know how I can troubleshoot and fix this issue.

---

### Upgrade

In addition, I just found an "**EventID: 4 - Error: php-8.1.10**" event in the Windows Event Viewer under System Management Events.

The event occurred during a period when I was not using the computer.

As a result, I went to the terminal to check the PHP version and discovered an error:

`PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.15 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0`

Suddenly, I am unable to use both Python and PHP, and I'm unsure if there is a common reason behind this issue.

Interestingly, just before the occurrence of the PHP Warning (with a time difference of a few seconds), there was another error in the Event Viewer stating "Event: 12 - Keeper - Invalid access code."

Comment: This sounds more of an issue for the IT guys at your company

Comment: @PeterYes, I have consulted IT, but they currently don't know the cause of the problem and are investigating it. That's why I'm here to see if anyone has encountered a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used two method solved these error:

1. Fix PHP Warning: vcruntime140.dll 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build

   https://studyopedia.com/errors-resolved/fix-php-warning-vcruntime140-dll-not-compatible/
2. Fix Python Permission Denied

   execute `sfc /scannow` in terminal.

(These errors are likely due to a computer restart, which resulted in missing files)